# CentOS 6.6 kickstart failing suddenly when including the 'updates' repo

Tags: centos6, kickstart

Suddenly this week my CentOS 6.6 kickstart is failing with:

`A fatal error occurred when installing the <rpm.hdr object at 0x4981cd0> package. This could indicate errors when reading the installation media. Installation cannot continue`

When I remove the CentOS 6 update repository from the kickstart profile, I can kickstart the system and re-applying the /etc/yum.repos.d/... files afterwards, I am able to install all recent updates.

Somebody out there experiencing the same ?

This is the ks-file - I even reduced it to the base packages - same error:

```
authconfig --enableshadow --enablemd5 --enablecache
bootloader --location=mbr
clearpart --all --initlabel
text
firewall --disabled
firstboot --disable
keyboard us
lang en_US.UTF-8
url --url=$tree
$yum_repo_stanza
$SNIPPET('network_config')
reboot
rootpw rootpw
selinux --disabled
skipx
timezone --utc US/Eastern
install
zerombr
part /boot --fstype ext3 --size=500
part / --fstype ext4 --size=9500
part /home --fstype xfs --size=1 --grow
part swap --size=4096

%packages
@base

%pre
$SNIPPET('log_ks_pre')
$SNIPPET('pre_install_network_config')
$SNIPPET('pre_anamon')

%packages
$SNIPPET('func_install_if_enabled')
$SNIPPET('puppet_install_if_enabled')

%post
... some post actions
%end
```

Comment: Please show the contents of your kickstart file.

Comment: Confirmed as a bug:
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=50709